# Aromatic enol is not possible in...?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

How to solve this kind of problems. What determines their stability?

Comment: Welcome! Homework questions must display some effort. Please include your attempt/thoughts on the problem, to avoid the deletion of this question.

Comment: When a ketone undergoes tautomerism to form an enol, where is the new double bond?

Answer (score 1):

This is a strange question - isn't it possible to form an aromatic enol in all 4 cases? #3 is the least obvious, but will still proceed:

[image]

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, vote me down if so!